# How to connect texture scaling?

Tags: geometry-nodes, shader-nodes

Is there a way to connect the density/width control to the x-axis control of the texture scaling?

Also if you find some major flaws in the geo setup feel free to tell it :)

[image: First example]
[image: Second example]
[image: Geo tree]
Geometry Nodes setup
[image: Shader tree]
Shader nodes setup

Answer (score 0):

Since you unfortunately didn't share your blend file with us, I can only show you with an abstracted example:

[image]
[image]

First, I instantiate a grid with dimensions 1x1 along a mesh line.

I use the distance of the points at the same time as a scaling factor for the instances.

Additionally I capture this value with `Store Named Attribute` in the *Face Corner* domain of the geometry.

This scale factor is then read in the shader with the node `Attribute`, and the texture coordinates is multiplied with it.

[image]
<sub>*Blender 3.3+*</sub>